# Elastic Beanstalk Nginx not receiving POST requests

Tags: node.js, post, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have 3 Elastic Beanstalk, load balanced instances running a NodeJS application behind an Nginx proxy. A while ago, I came across a very strange error. One of the instances was not receiving a post request. Here is what was happening.

My application login page was loading correctly through a GET request. Once I input the credentials and hit the login button, I could see the POST request being made to the server. Nothing would happen and the request would time out after a while. I ssh-ed into that instance and checked the Nginx access logs. It seems the GET requests were going through but the POST request was not even hitting the Nginx server. The same code was deployed on other 2 instances and was working fine.

I restarted that instance and everything was back to normal.

Here is my Nginx configuration at `/etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf`:

```
upstream nodejs {
    server 127.0.0.1:8081;
    keepalive 256;
}

server {
    listen 8080;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }   
}
```

My question is what could be causing such a strange behavior where only the POST requests were not going through ?

Comment: Can you add nginx config or logs?

Comment: @vanadium23 Added it to the question. Is this the one you asked for? May not be able to provide the logs :(